# Get incremental count of list for all the elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list with 24 million elements and I want to increment count of each element iteratively and store the count in another list in faster way. For example, my list is:

`a=['bike','bike','jeep','horse','horse','horse','flight','flight','cycle']`

My expected output is

`[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]`

The code i used is

```
z=[]
for i in a:
   z.append(a.count(i))
```

But my output is bit different

```
[2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1]
```

My order of this newly created list is also important and should be based on my list(a). Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Based on your expected output, looks like you need the count of the list element till that index and not the complete count of the element in the list. a.count(i) gives the complete count of the element in the list.

Comment: Use `z = [a[:i+1].count(val) for (i, val) in enumerate(a)]` to compute your list

Comment: What do you need that result for? As you plan it the values are expensive to calculate and need to be related by index. In most use-cases a `Counter` should be more helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your expected output, since you need the count of elements till that index of the list at which you are iterating at that point of time, the below code should work:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a=['bike','bike','jeep','horse','horse','horse','flight','flight','cycle']

a_dict = defaultdict(int)
a_output = []

for x in a:
    a_dict[x] += 1
    a_output.append(a_dict[x])

print(a_output)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks @jay..the code is also faster for 24 million..it executed in less than 2 seconds. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution -

```
a=['bike','bike','jeep','horse','horse','horse','flight','flight','cycle']
countArr = []
temp = {}
for i in a:
    if i in temp:
        temp[i]+=1
        countArr.append(temp.get(i))
    else:
        temp[i] = 1
        countArr.append(temp.get(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary and a `for` loop to accomplish this:

```
counts = {}
a = ['bike','bike','jeep','horse','horse','horse','flight','flight','cycle']
z = []
for i in a:
    if i in counts:
        counts[i] += 1
    else:
        counts[i] = 1
    z.append(counts[i])

print(z)
# [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]
```

You can also do this fun hacky thing with a list comprehension, which exploits the evaluation order of tuples and does essentially the same as the above `for` loop but condensed into one line:

```
counts = {}
z = [(counts.__setitem__(i, counts[i] + 1 if i in counts else 1), counts[i])[1] for i in a]
print(z)
# [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks @Green Cloak Guy for your answer. I tried another answer provided by Jay. Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 0):

you can use sub-array count :

```
a=['bike','bike','jeep','horse','horse','horse','flight','flight','cycle']

z=[]

i = 0
while i < len(a):
    #print(a[0:i])
    #print(a[i])
    z.append(a[0:i].count(a[i]) + 1)
    i+= 1

print(z)
```